# how to use array_diff

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

this is the print_r of the arrays and the last one is the result:

```
Array ( [0] => 28 [1] => 29 [2] => 30 [3] => 31 [4] => 32 [5] => 33 [6] => 34 ) 

Array ( [0] => 28 [1] => 29 [2] => 30 [3] => 31 [4] => 32 [5] => 33 [6] => 34 [7] => 35 ) 

result:
Array ( [1] => 29 [2] => 30 [3] => 31 [4] => 32 [5] => 33 [6] => 34 )
```

I want to get an array that holds 35 entries since its the only one missing and for some reason I get entire first array if I put the second array first in the function I get all entries of the second one.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: If you were just wondering how to use that function, check the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) it is pretty simple really.

Answer (score 0):

When using `array_diff` the **first** array is used and checked against any other arrays passed.

Your `35` is found like so:

```
$array1 = Array ( 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34 );

$array2 = Array ( 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35 );

$diff = array_diff($array2, $array1);

print_r($diff);
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [7] => 35
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the array function [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) you can achieve what you are looking for. Compares `$arr2` against `$arr1` and returns the values in `$arr2` that are not present in `$arr1`.

```
$arr1 = range(28, 34);
$arr2 = range(28, 35);

$arr = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
print_r($arr); // Array ( [7] => 35 )
```